# Date object with year and month only

Tags: python, date, dictionary, key

Is it possible to create [date](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) object with year and month only? I don't need day.

```
In [5]: from datetime import date

In [6]: date(year=2013, month=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a84d4034b10c> in <module>()
----> 1 date(year=2013, month=1)

TypeError: Required argument 'day' (pos 3) not found
```

I'm using the date object as key in my dictionary and January 20 must have the same key as January 21, because they are in same month and year.

I used a simple integer before that as a month number. Unfortunately I need to know the year too!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, you can't do that. For your usecase, use a tuple instead:

```
key = (2013, 1)
```

Since you don't need to do date manipulations on the value a tuple more than suffices.

Answer (score 18):

As an addition to other answer, you can use namedtuple.

```
from collections import namedtuple
MyDate = namedtuple('MyDate', ['month', 'year'])
dkey = MyDate(year=2013, month=1)
```

Comment: Good answer! It is really a valuable addition.

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(year=2013, month=1, day=4)
str(date.year) + '-' + str(date.month)
```

Comment: This is a poor answer without any explanation. It also fails to address the problem asked. The OP wants to create a date object without supplying an argument for `day`, it's not about the output of a date object.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `datetime`, you must follow its attributes. Here I quote it from the official website:

> "An idealized naive date, assuming the current Gregorian calendar
>   always was, and always will be, in effect. Attributes: year, month,
>   and day."

So, you can't ignore day and remember to give assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This implements a class which is just like datetime.date, but you need not specify the day.  i.e. It allows you to "create date object with year and month only."

```py
class Mdate(datetime.date):
    """ A datetime.date where day doesn't matter. """

    def __new__(cls, year, month):
        """Python calls __new__ instead of __init__ for immutable objects."""
        return super().__new__(cls, year, month, 1)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Because you're implementing __new__ you also need __repr__ or else you get
        TypeError: __new__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given."""
        return '{0}({1}, {2}, 1)'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.year, self.month)

    def __reduce__(self):
        """You need __reduce__ to support pickling."""
        return (self.__class__, (self.year, self.month))
```

I have a boatload of code where the day of month is irrelevant, and removing the day from the date constructor clarifies that code.

Sample use:

```
d = Mdate(2020, 12)
```